# Align Paper Icon and Text left?

Tags: javascript, html, css, polymer, polymer-1.0

I have the following Google Polymer structure

```
<paper-drawer-panel>
   <div drawer> 

     <paper-header-panel>
       <paper-toolbar>Drawer Header</paper-toolbar>
       <div>
           <paper-icon-item>
              <iron-icon icon="favorite" item-icon></iron-icon>
              Add List
           </paper-icon-item>
       </div>
       </paper-header-panel>

   </div>
   <div main> Main panel... </div>
 </paper-drawer-panel>
```

My result looks like this:

[image]

The icons and the text are centered aligned. How can I align them left like in the following image:

[image]

**How can I align paper icon and text left?**

Comment: Have you tried the CSS property `text-align: left`? You could put that on your `<paper-icon-item>` element or your `<paper-header-panel>`

Comment: ``text-align: left`` does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Make sure to import `iron-flex-layout/classes/iron-flex-layout.html`

Update your code as below

```
<paper-drawer-panel>
 <div drawer> 

  <paper-header-panel>
   <paper-toolbar>Drawer Header</paper-toolbar>
   <div class="horizonatal layout">
       <paper-icon-item>
          <iron-icon icon="favorite" item-icon></iron-icon>
          Add List
       </paper-icon-item>
       <div class="flex"></div>
   </div>
  </paper-header-panel>
 </div>
 <div main> Main panel... </div>
</paper-drawer-panel>
```

Comment: No this does not change anything.

Comment: There is a typo in the code example. Using class to add layout also does not work. Try @apply(--layout-horizontal) in the styling.

Answer (score 0):

See the demo, It is left aligned without any styling, You have to make sure that you are importing the paper-elements(which are required here `paper-drawer-panel`,`paper-header-panel`,etc.) before using it, I think some other style is causing this issue.

```html
<head>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/master/webcomponents.js"></script>
  
  <base href="http://polygit.org/components/">
<link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">

<!-- import the paper-elements which are used, Here importing all of them at once -->
<link rel="import" href="paper-elements/paper-elements.html">
</head>
<body>
<paper-drawer-panel>
  
<div  drawer>
     <paper-header-panel>
       <paper-toolbar>Drawer Header</paper-toolbar>
       <div>
           <paper-icon-item>
              <iron-icon icon="favorite" item-icon></iron-icon>
              Add List
           </paper-icon-item>
       </div>
       <div>
           <paper-icon-item>
              <iron-icon icon="favorite" item-icon></iron-icon>
              Clear All
           </paper-icon-item>
       </div>
       </paper-header-panel>
</div>
   
   <div main style="background:lightgray;"> Main panel... </div>
 </paper-drawer-panel>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late, but I was having the same issue and I've found that reducing the icon area's width the content of the paper-icon-item aligns left correctly:

`paper-icon-item {
    --paper-item-icon-width: 10px;
}`

Hope it'll be useful for someone.